# Checking out git repo to case-insensitive FS

Tags: git

Relatively new to git; working with some git repos that unfortunately have files/dirs that are named identically except for capitalization, e.g.

```
Bar/
Bar/one
Bar/oNe
Foo/
Foo/Two
foo/
foo/Two
foo/three
```

I sometimes have to work on this sort of repo from an OSX box w/ the default HFS+ filesystem, which is case-insensitive, so when I clone or check out this repo, the namespace collisions cause me to lose some files:

```
Bar/
Bar/oNe
Foo/
Foo/Two
Foo/three
```

Renaming the originals isn't an option at the moment, nor is using a different FS on that box.

1. Is there some way to deal with this by merging back only specific files? e.g. if I want to work on `Bar/oNe`, something like:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git checkout master Bar/one # clobbers the Bar/oNe I have locally
   [edit Bar/one]
   [do something to marge Bar/one back in without affecting Bar/oNe, which now appears to have been deleted in my working copy]
   ```
2. The `Foo/` directory is a legacy one that I don't need to touch, but it seems to consistently win in the namespace collisions, i.e. the `Foo/Two` that I end up with is from `Foo/Two` and not from `foo/Two`.  Given that I don't need to touch that dir in any way, is there any way to easily specify *not* to pull it down in a check-out, so that I don't need to then check out the desired folder manually as per the first half of #1?

Comment: I understand you can't change the filesystem, but can you create a loopback filesystem/disk image that is case-sensitive, and work inside it?

Comment: There is (as far as I know) no tool to work with these, but there really should be: in particular, one ought to be able to tell git to map file names through some invert-able and/or user-supplied name-map (a la smudge and clean filters, almost).  For part 2 there's sparse checkout but IIRC last time I poked at it (not very thoroughly) it broke because git detected the HFS+ case insensitivity and thought both files were candidates for the sparse checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to work around this issue is to use Disk Utility to create a disk image using a 'case sensitive, journaled' filesystem, mount that, and check out your repository into that filesystem.

Open "Disk Utility", select "New Blank Image..." from the file menu, and then select "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)" for the Format, and configure other things similar to this:

[image: creating a new disk image]

This will create the image and mount it at `/Volumes/gitwork`, assuming you've used the same names that I used in this example.  Then in the Terminal you can:

```
$ cd /Volumes/gitwork
$ git clone http://host/myrepo.git
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, based on wnoise's suggestion of a loopback device, but since larsks spelled out the details of how to do so before I could come back and spell it out myself...